# Can we use curl command to push/pull docker image to nexus 3 repository

Tags: docker, curl

I have a requirement to push/pull the docker image to/from the nexus 3 repositories. Can we use curl commands for this activity? 
As docker installation is not allowed by our Infra team we have to find an alternate way to achieve this.

I have tried below curl commands to pull and push image respectively. Please correct me if this is the correct way.
While downloading an image I don't get any error. 
But while uploading, my requirement is to create a new folder(folder name is my project name) inside the docker repository (pre-existing) and inside this, I have to upload the image.

```
Downloading the Docker image
curl -u uname:password -O https://nexusURL/dockerimagename

Uploading image
curl -u uname:password --ftp-create-dirs -T dockerimagename https://nexusURL/<newfoldername_to_be_created>/
```

```
Error while uploading
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 400</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /FRAI/v2/anna/orchestrator/manifests/v1.10.12. Reason:
<pre>    Not a Docker request</pre></p>
<hr /><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.7.v20160115</a><hr/>
</body>
```

The ideal output after upload should be

```
https://nexusURL/PROJECTNAME/dockerimage
```

Comment: Have you been able to upload dockerimage without creating the folder ?

Comment: Do you have any other cloud storage tool installed on target machine (Where docker installation is blocked) ?

Comment: We don't have anyother tool. But if you can suggest I can request our Infra team to install anysuch.

Comment: And I am totally unable to upload any dockerimage with the above shared commands. (inside or outside folder)

Comment: Ask them to provide any ftp/sftp, or dropbox on target machine. then you can upload tar file over there of image and then download that tar file from that ftp or dropbox

Comment: Any idea ? Is it not possible with curl.. because for earlier nexus 2 version, we used to upload zip files using curl. Now for uploading docker images I face problem using curl